# How to protect the excel selected cell using nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, exceljs

Hi i have create and download the excel file at run time by using "exceljs"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

now I want to protect the excel cell at run time is it possible to protect excel file. can anyone tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) you cann't work with protected files/cells. This is highlighted in [v0.2.24 Release notes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#release-history)

Comment: Hi galkin, is there any possible way to set cell value accept only number at run time

Comment: Hi, Vinoth. Unfortunately, not